# Need advice on python (3.10) + selenium (4.15.2)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, daemon, autoit

I'm not an expert on `Python` nor `Selenium` despite having some simple projects working combining them.
I already have a working solution to my problem, however **I'd like you to comment on it**.
I have simplified the code to make it easier for you to focus on the important aspects.

I have an `AutoIt` script that calls ([RunWait](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RunWait.htm)) a compiled (`pyinstaller`) version of my python code which opens a browser through the Selenium API, login, perform some actions on the site and logout.
Since this is done many times I wanted to keep a browser session active to save time. To do this I save the `command_executor_url` and `session_id` to a file and retrieve it every time I run this script or create a new instance if necessary.

The key is to let the main process exit (to make `RunWait` return) but, keep the driver (`chromedriver`) running (and listening to incoming connections), so the main process creates a daemon process.

This is the entry point. (My thoughts are in the comments)

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()

    # connect to existing instance or create a new one
    driver = get_driver()

    # login, perform some actions, logout through Selenium API
    # driver.get(...
```

These are the main functions.

```py
def create_instance(sem):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = get_chrome_options())
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    write_instance_data(driver, PATH_TO_INSTACE_DATA)

    # Instance created, let parent process connect to it.
    sem.release()

    # This is awful and I don't undestand what happens here...
    # This function seems to terminate despite having this loop.
    # Maybe, whenever the parent exits, this child exit, even when daemon is set to True.
    # However chromedriver keep runnning.
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)

def get_driver():
    while True:
        try:
            command_executor_url, session_id = read_instace_data(PATH_TO_INSTACE_DATA)

            # Might throw an exception 
            driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor_url, options = get_chrome_options())

            # Remote opens a new window. I don't need it.
            driver.close()

            driver.session_id = session_id

            # If the window I do need is closed, just create a new instance.
            # I don't know (yet) whether I can open a new window if it is the case.
            if len(driver.window_handles) == 0:
                raise Exception("No window available")

            break

        except Exception as e:
            sem = Semaphore(0)

            p = Process(target = create_instance, args = (sem,), daemon = True)
            p.start()

            # Wait until instance is created.
            sem.acquire()

    return driver
```